# "cannot move out borrowed content" when assigning a variable from a struct field

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I'm learning Rust and I'm fighting against the borrow checker.

I have a basic `Point` structure. I have a `scale` function that modifies all the coordinates of the point. I would like to call this method from another method named `convert`:

```
struct AngleUnit;

struct Point {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
    unit: AngleUnit,
}

fn factor(_from: AngleUnit, _to: AngleUnit) -> f32 {
    1.0
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: f32, y: f32, z: f32, unit: AngleUnit) -> Point {
        Point { x, y, z, unit }
    }

    fn scale(&mut self, factor: f32) {
        self.x *= factor;
        self.y *= factor;
        self.z *= factor;
    }

    fn convert(&mut self, unit: AngleUnit) {
        let point_unit = self.unit;
        self.scale(factor(point_unit, unit));
    }
}
```

Now I have the following error:

```
cannot move out of borrowed content
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *complete* error message states:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:26:26
   |
26 |         let point_unit = self.unit;
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^
   |                          |
   |                          cannot move out of borrowed content
   |                          help: consider borrowing here: `&self.unit`
```

Which is useful to understand where the move is occurring.

The *simplest* solution is to implement either `Copy` or `Clone` for your `AngleUnit` type. If it's `Copy`, your code will work as-is. If it's only `Clone`, you have to explicitly call `.clone()` to make a duplicate.

If your type cannot be made `Copy`, then you can use references, as the compiler suggests:

```
fn factor(_from: &AngleUnit, _to: &AngleUnit) -> f32 {
    1.0
}
```

```
fn convert(&mut self, unit: AngleUnit) {
    let point_unit = &self.unit;
    self.scale(factor(point_unit, &unit));
}
```

The original problem all boils down to this line:

```
let point_unit = self.unit;
```

What should the value of `point_unit` be?

If we *moved* the value from `self.unit` to `point_unit`, then what would the value of `self.unit` be? The "easy" solution would be that it is undefined memory, but experience has shown that we programmers will screw that up and introduce exciting-to-debug problems.

We could copy the value automatically, but what would happen if `AngleUnit` were a type that took up 10 MiB of space? Then an innocent looking line just sucked up a bunch of memory and time. That's not very nice either.

Instead, Rust makes it so that types are *moved* by default and you cannot leave an object in an undefined state. Certain types can opt into the ability to be automatically copied — this is the `Copy` trait. You can also allow types to be explicitly copied — the `Clone` trait. You can also obtain a *reference* to an existing value and pass that around. The borrow checker will prevent you from using that reference after it is no longer valid.

Comment: Nice answer; however, visitors from google need to read a lot, although the solution is `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` in many cases. Maybe emphasize your "The simplest solution is..." section :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to mark the `AngleUnit` with the `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` attribute in order to allow Rust to *copy* the `AngleUnit` from one variable to another, like you do in `let point_unit = self.unit`.

By default, Rust is only allowed to *move* your structures since *moving* is generally more efficient than making a copy. For instance, if your structure would have had a `Vec` or a `String` in it then to *copy* the structure the program would have to allocate new memory for `Vec` or `String` contents on the heap. Whereas *moving* a `Vec` or a `String` incurs no extra heap allocations.

In this case I guess the `AngleUnit` is just a wrapper around a small primitive value so it's completely okay to *copy* it.

Here's [an example of your code with the attribute added](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=04daa9a35c63af68419c51b6139c43dd):

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct AngleUnit;

struct Point {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
    unit: AngleUnit,
}

fn factor(from: AngleUnit, to: AngleUnit) -> f32 {
    1f32
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: f32, y: f32, z: f32, unit: AngleUnit) -> Point {
        Point { x, y, z, unit }
    }

    fn scale(&mut self, factor: f32) {
        self.x *= factor;
        self.y *= factor;
        self.z *= factor;
    }

    fn convert(&mut self, unit: AngleUnit) {
        let point_unit = self.unit;
        self.scale(factor(point_unit, unit));
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are moving `self.unit` at:

```
let point_unit = self.unit;
```

Try using references or making the type `Copy`.